# Gray or yellow background for questions and answers using > and >!

Tags: support, feature-request, spoilers

Many times I have asked myself why there is no longer a grey or other colour background as there was a few months ago using the `>` command. Using a smartphone you can see the color of the background. The visual aspect is important. You can only see the background when you set the `>!` command, which makes the question visible when you hover the mouse pointer. Is there any possibility to restore it in all communities?

> Just an example without gray background.

> Just an example without gray background and formula: $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Comment: There's a question announcing this on Meta SE. Pretty much everyone who isn't the designer thinks it's a bad idea. They said they wanted to make it more like (git?)

Comment: @MattSamuel Hi and thank you very much for your information. It is very ugly without a background. It is a visual impact: your eyes immediately point to the background of the question and then read the rest. At least that happens for me.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343919/some-improvements-to-blockquotes/344876#344876

Comment: @MattSamuel I give you my sincere "grazie assai". I have written a comment to Aaron Shekey♦ on your link.

Comment: I don't really think that ([meta-tag:specific-question]) really fits this question. The purpose of this tag is described in [the tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info).

Comment: There are browser add-ons (like Stylus for Firefox -- don't install Stylish, which was the original version but was taken over by marketers) that allow one to modify specific HTML fragments on pages from specific domains. I'm not very good with it, and it depends of the original HTML being regular enough that you can reliably locate the section you want modified, but if you get no love from the SE staff you might be able to fix it in your own browser with one of these.